# Access to a class only in framework

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating a framework for iOS with [this tool](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) and I want to manage the visibility of my classes. Of course, I put my headers in corrects sections in my Build Phases > Copy Headers .
But when I add my framework in a new project, I still can access to classes (and their functions) stored in the Private section. I want my class "public" in my framework but "private" outside.

Is it possible ?

Thanks.

Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Objective-C runtime, everything is in the same global namespace. You can hide things by not including them in public headers, but they're still there and can be discovered and accessed using the lower level runtime APIs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
So I can't organize my framework like I organize a Java Jar ?
Do you have an idea of how I can create my framework with more security please ?

Comment: Can you give more details about what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Actually, I want that my internals classes can see each other but external classes (classes which used the framework) can only see internals classes which have public headers. Sorry if I am not clear, english is not my mother tongue.

Comment: The runtime is always shared, so using something like `objc_getClassList()` will always enable someone to find out what classes exist.